# How to know exactly which Foundation Modal window is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I have two modal windows defined in my HTML:

```
<div class="reveal" id="modal-1" data-reveal>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal 1" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <p>content 1</p>
</div>

<div class="reveal" id="modal-2" data-reveal>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal 2" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <p>content 2</p>
</div>
```

Depending on the result of particular function, one of those modal will be called (opened) by calling either `$('#modal-1').foundation('open');` or `$('#modal-2').foundation('open');`.

That works perfectly fine. I can easily check if any of modal windows is opened because once I call `.foundation('open')`, a new class is appended into `body` called `is-reveal-open`. That's fine but...

Question: **How to determine exactly which window is opened?** I don't want to loop through DOM etc. Does Foundation provide some sort of helper method for that? Any thoughts how to do this in the best way?

PS. I use foundation-sites@6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, considering you have multiple instances of modal objects to query, the simplest thing to do is:

```
$(".modal:visible")
```

It will return the DOM node of your modal

ps: in foundation 5 selector is `$(".reveal-modal:visible")` not sure which one will be good for you